# What is happening at the end of this circuit? Why is the voltage zero at the bottom?

Tags: physics

[image]

What is happening to the voltage at the bottom? Why is it zero? How does the voltage go back to the positive terminal?

Comment: Where did the image come from?

Comment: why should the voltage not be zero?

Comment: Does Falstad auto-assign ground? Regular SPICE would just throw an error message that ground is not defined in the schematic above.

Comment: This is from https://www.falstad.com

Comment: I am new to this topic. Is the simulation not properly grounded?

Comment: There is no Voltage, but there is Current. I am comparing values from a worksheet. I got 3.36 Volts for after the Resistors of 95 and 82. But here it is 0.

Comment: [Falstad's Circuit Simulator Applet](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/) probably automatically assigns ground when adding a voltage source.

Comment: You got the voltage drop across the 2 resistors in parallel right - the applet even displays 3.4V on the top right, which is 3.36V rounded. Remember that a voltage drop is equal to difference in potential, so 3.4-0=3.4.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

It's zero at the bottom because someone has decided that it is.  That said, it's connected to the negative terminal of the battery, so that seems a reasonable choice of what to call 0V.

A voltmeter has two probes.  That's because you can only really measure the voltage from one point to another.  But it's tedious to have to say which two points you're measuring between every time you state a voltage.  So it's normal to pick one point in a circuit, call it 0V, and measure the voltage from that to anything else.  Of course, if you measure the voltage between that point and itself, the meter will show 0V, so that's all good.

---

Voltages don't "go back to" anywhere.  A battery is a device that creates a voltage between its two terminals.

Answer (score 0):

> What is happening to the voltage at the bottom? Why is it zero? How does the voltage go back to the positive terminal?

Nothing is happening to the voltage at the bottom.

The other voltages are with reference to the negative rail. Hence it is marked '0 V'.